# Are 12 word wallet seeds safe?

Tags: mnemonic-seed

I understand 12 word seeds mean there is 128 bits of 'security' but what does that mean? Would i need to worry about this being brute forced? If it was brute forced would having to scan the blockchain for every attempt not make that impossible/take forever? thanks guy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/mymonero-and-monero-wallet-seed) for considerations on security.

Note that it is only partially true that brute forcing would involve having to scan the blockchain for every attempt. If you're doing a random search to find some random address with a balance then yes, you need to scan the blockchan for each to know whether you've hit the jackpot. If you're doing a targeted brute-force against a known address (or a list of them) then - no. This is because just rolling the seeds until the resulting address matches is enough. To actually see the balance, you'd still have to scan, though.